# Write a <img> element inside of a <li> element with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been working with Javascript for a little bit now. My code below has various pictures defined as an object. Now I want to put these images as `<img>` inside `<li>` tags. However, I am experiencing some difficulty with this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++){
    var newImage = document.createElement('img')
    newImage.setAttribute('class', 'image-item')
    newImage.setAttribute('alt', pictures[i].name)
    newImage.src = pictures[i].url

    var liItem = document.createElement('li')
    liItem.innerHTML = newImage

    document.getElementById('pictures').appendChild(liItem)
    console.log(liItem)
}
```

Any idea on how to resolve this? The result has to look like this:

```
<li><img src="picture1.jpg" alt="loremipsum"></li>
```

Right now console tells me the following: 
[image: Screenshot of the console in Chrome.]

Comment: instead of liItem.innerHTML = newImage, can you try appendchild

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel hey buddy..your above comments point to me?

Comment: Sorry missed a line, I will delete my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `liItem.innerHTML = newImage` to `liItem.appendChild(newImage)`

Answer (score 0):

The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element. so you should change `liItem.innerHTML = newImage` to `liItem.appendChild(newImage)`